# Maven plugin which calls gradle

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, gradle

Is there a maven plugin available which calls gradle?

It might sound strange, but my company still uses maven and I want to make some experiments with gradle on our jenkins server. :-)

Comment: It seems that better idea is to just add `build.gradle` with `wrapper` configured and just run it on Jenkins with reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I do not have any administration priviliges on our jenkins server. :-(

Comment: So go to person who has it and discuss the problem. Trust me, it doesn't make any sense to run gradle via maven.

Comment: What comes to my head is that You can make use to maven-exec-plugin or something like that, but really, don't go this way. Try locally.

Comment: maybe the groovy plugin will allow you to run gradle: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVENPLUS/Home

Comment: @EhmKa, why exactly do you need admin priviliges on jenkins ? Do you need them to create a new jenkins job, or to install gradle, or ..? Since, If you can create a jenkins job + you use the gradle wrapper (ref comments Opal), you can start experimenting. If you can't even create a jenkins job, your only option is to use maven-exec-plugin and the wrapper, but I also would not go there.